# Getting a value of a clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a bunch of dummy links in a jQuery Mobile accordian. By dummy links I mean the that href is just "#". The list is created dynamically by another function and a value is stored in the element by using the value attribute. A loop writes the list like this

```
'<li value="' + result.ID + '"><a href="#">' + result.Name + '</a></li>'
```

I am having trouble grabbing that value when I click on the link. I am currently using this event handler

```
$(document).on('click', '#openCallsList li a', function () {

});
```

When a link is clicked I want to have the value associated with it so I can grab some data from a database ( I know how to do this) and then create a dialog window (which I also know how to do). I am just lost on how to get the value I stored with the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
$(document).on('click', '#openCallsList li a', function () {
    console.log($(this).closest('li').attr('value'));
});
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance but where do I find the log to see if it is working correctly.

Comment: To view the console, you would want to pull up a web inspector in Safari, Firefox or Chrome. Not sure where to get it in IE though.

Comment: In later versions of IE, you can just do F12 to get the console.

Answer (score 3):

Although you could grab the `value` attribute from the `<li>` tag, this is invalid HTML. The `value` attribute has been deprecated.

> This attribute has been deprecated in HTML 4.01. Therefore its use is no longer recommended.

source: http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/li.html#value

What I would suggest is changing it to something like this:

```
'<li id="' + result.ID + '"><a href="#">' + result.Name + '</a></li>'
```

And then use

```
$(document).on('click', '#openCallsList li a', function () {
    var value = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    // or you could use the closest('li') function too.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is full code:

**HTML Code:**

```
<ul id ='openCallsList'>
    <li value='12'><a href="#">12</a></li>
    <li value='13'><a href="#">13</a></li>
    <li value='14'><a href="#">14</a></li>
    <li value='15'><a href="#">15</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Java Script Code:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#openCallsList li a', function () {
    alert($(this).parent().attr('value'));
});
```